# bash if elif statement always prints first value

Tags: linux, bash

For some reason, the first value is always printed. I can't figure out the reason behind it. Any ideas?

```
#!/bin/bash
config="update_release"
if [[ "$config"=="update" ]]; then
   schema_list="main_schemas"
elif [[ "$config"=="update_release" ]] ; then
   schema_list="release_schemas"
elif [[ "$config"=="update_maintenance" ]]; then
   schema_list="maintenance_schemas"
fi
echo $schema_list
```

I tried many things including single =, single [] but nothing seems to be working at all.

Comment: Try [shellcheck](http://shellcheck.net)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to add whitespace to the conditions:

```
#!/bin/bash
config="update_release"
if [ "$config" == "update" ]; then
   schema_list="main_schemas"
elif [ "$config" == "update_release" ] ; then
   schema_list="release_schemas"
elif [ "$config" == "update_maintenance" ]; then
   schema_list="maintenance_schemas"
fi
echo $schema_list
```

Answer (score 2):

This,

```
if [ "$config" == "update_release" ]
```

is synonym for

```
if [ "$config" = "update_release" ]
```

**Note the whitespace framing the `=`**

I think that you should rethink the logic of what you are trying to make

```
[[ $config == update* ]]    # True if $config starts with an "update" (pattern matching).
[[ $config  == "update*" ]] # True if $config is equal to update* (literal matching).

[ $config  == update* ]     # File globbing and word splitting take place.
[ "$config" == "update*" ]  # True if $config is equal to update* (literal matching).
```

Answer (score 1):

OR Try with single brackets and single equals sign"="

```
#!/bin/bash
config="update_release"
if [ "$config" = "update" ]; then
   schema_list="main_schemas"
elif [ "$config" = "update_release" ] ; then
   schema_list="release_schemas"
elif [ "$config" = "update_maintenance" ]; then
   schema_list="maintenance_schemas"
fi
echo $schema_list
```